# Cómo hago para modificar texto de un archivo .txt en java?

Tags: java, c++

Resulta que debo hacer un traductor de JAVA a C++, donde debe leer un archivo .txt con sintaxis de JAVA, y crear uno nuevo a partir de ese que haga lo mismo que hace el archivo .txt de JAVA pero debe estar transformado ahora a sintaxis de C++. Gracias :)
No tiene que ser algo muy complicado, lo necesario es que el archivo a traducir haga los cambios de linea que tengan que hacerse para que sea un archivo c++, no importa si lo abres en una IDE de c++ y no corre el codigo traducido, lo importante es, que los cambios que deban hacerse, se hagan bien:

Debe traducir cosas como:(Sintaxis original -> Sintaxis traducida)

- Los mensajes de salida y entrada(System.out.print(), los de la biblioteca scanner) a sus respectivos en c++ -> cout y cin.
- Las bibliotecas de java -> Bibliotecas de c++.

Este es el codigo que pienso usar como .txt a ser traducido y crear uno nuevo a partir de este:

```
import java.util.*;

public class code{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

Debería crearse luego en un archivo diferente el traducido a c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << hola << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Avance lectura y escritura de archivos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file = new File("/Volumes/20xx/code.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            String texto = "Hola";
            Scanner sc;
           try{ 
                sc = new Scanner(file);
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    String linea = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(linea);

                    }
                for(int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++){
                    fw.write(texto.charAt(i));

                }
                fw.close();
                sc.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Qué materia estás llevando para que se te pida crear un traductor de código?

Comment: En mi universidad se llama programación 2, y es todo basado en el lenguaje de java

Comment: Entonces me imagino que el código fuente  a traducir será básico. Agrega en la pregunta ejemplos de la sintaxis en Java que será traducida a C++ para tener una idea de la complejidad del requerimiento.

Comment: Listo amigo, espero, puedas entender mejor ahora :)

Comment: Entonces funcionaría traduciendo lineas completas? si encuentra : import.java.util.*; lo reemplaza por #include<iostream>. Si encuentra System.out.println("Hola"); lo traduce a cout << "hola" << endl;

Comment: Eso es correcto :)

Answer (score 0):

El código contiene dos ejemplos de conversión en la función `convertirLinea()`, para cada caso nuevo se deben agregar otras condiciones para la traducción ahí ya depende de ti implementar la lógica, por ejemplo para convertir `public static void main(String[]args)`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //crear archivos de entrada y salida
        File archivoEntrada = new File("/ruta/archivo/uno.text");
        File archivoSalida = new File("/ruta/archivo/dos.txt");

        //crear stream para escribir al archivo de salida
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(archivoSalida);


        Scanner sc;

        try {
            sc = new Scanner(archivoEntrada);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                //leer archivo de entrada linea por linea
                String lineaOriginal = sc.nextLine();

                //convertir linea leída a su equivalente en Cpp
                String lineaConvertida = convertirLinea(lineaOriginal);

                //escribir la linea convertida convertida en el archivo de salida
                fw.write(lineaConvertida);

            }
            //cerrar los streams
            fw.close();
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }

    }

    private static String convertirLinea(String lineaOriginal){

        //se evaluan todos los casos que pueden convertirse y se retorna
        //su equivalente
        if(lineaOriginal.contains("import.java.util"))
            return "#include<iostream>";


        if(lineaOriginal.contains("System.out.println"))
        {
            //extraer el texto que está dentro del println
            String[] partes = lineaOriginal.split("\"");
            return "cout << \""  + partes[1] + "\" cout << endl;";

        }

        return "";
    }
}
```